# Recorded Macro spoils time format in exported csv BUT csv exported while recording has desired time format

Tags: excel, vba, csv, export

VBA downloads quotes from google finance and puts into "Data" sheet. Date and time are in 1 column and are derived by calculation (except for 1st row).

Next step is to operate on data clean it and put it into consumable format. I work on date-time column and paste them as values and copy this sheet in a new workbook and save the sheet of new workbook as CSV. And i get my perfect csv at mentioned location.

Meanwhile, all these steps are getting recorded by Macro Recorder of excel.

When i run the excel i get a CSV... BUT.. that CSV ends up having spoiled Date and Time formats. For unknown reasons AM/PM are added to last column.

Please note that my System Time settings are US locale and i have modified it to show short date as dd-mm-yy and short time as HH:mm:ss.

You see there's no "tt" in my system settings. YET, excel somehow gives good results on saving manually, but when running same recorded vba it goes on to change date format to m-dd-yy and time format to hh:mm:ss and "tt" in next or last column !!

Can anyone please help me out of this bizarre situation ?

Any solution is welcome..

[file for reference](http://speedy.sh/UkJWK/DataImport-1.xlsm)

Comment: If you open the .csv file using notepad, what do you see?

Comment: Also, please update the question to include the relevant code

Comment: Manually done csv comes in dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss (date and time formats, respectively), in correct fashion.

VBA done csv always adds AM/PM in next column to time and changes date and time formats.

Just ran debug-->stepinto--> and saw that "TextToColumn" is not respecting the given "number format" in vba mode. Don't know why.

Paul -- i have attached the file as a link, do i still need to provide complete vba code in the question-body itself ?

thanks to both of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a well known problem with  `TextToColumns` in VBA.

Assuming we have:

```
14-09-2015 11:00:00
14-09-2015 12:00:00
14-09-2015 13:00:00
14-09-2015 14:00:00
```

In Column `A` which is not text but formatted date value with time.

And we have locale settings not to use AM/PM time.

Now we record a macro while using `Data - Text to Columns` to split the date from the time. We get in the spreadsheet in columns `A:C`:

```
14-09-2015 11:00:00 14.09.2015  11:00:00
14-09-2015 12:00:00 14.09.2015  12:00:00
14-09-2015 13:00:00 14.09.2015  13:00:00
14-09-2015 14:00:00 14.09.2015  14:00:00
```

The date format in column `B` is the default date format of our Excel. In my case the German date format.

And we get the following macro recorded:

```
Sub Makro1()
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

If we run this macro, we get:

```
14-09-2015 11:00:00 14.09.2015  11:00:00    AM
14-09-2015 12:00:00 14.09.2015  12:00:00    PM
14-09-2015 13:00:00 14.09.2015  01:00:00    PM
14-09-2015 14:00:00 14.09.2015  02:00:00    PM
```

Why?

VBA is running ever with en_US locale and `TextToColumns` does not provide a method to change this. So the `14-09-2015 13:00:00` in en_US locale looks like `09/14/2015 01:00:00 PM`. As you see, there are three columns and AM/PM.

As far as I know. there is no solution using `TextToColumns` with VBA for splitting date and time correctly and not using AM/PM.

So we need using another approach. Like this for example:

```
Sub Macro2()

 With ActiveSheet

  lLastRow = .Columns("A:A").Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  ReDim arrDate(1 To lLastRow) As Long
  ReDim arrTime(1 To lLastRow) As Double
  arrDateTimes = .Range("A1:A" & lLastRow).Value
  For lRow = LBound(arrDateTimes) To UBound(arrDateTimes)
   arrDate(lRow) = Int(arrDateTimes(lRow, 1))
   arrTime(lRow) = arrDateTimes(lRow, 1) - arrDate(lRow)
  Next
  .Range("B1:B" & lLastRow).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrDate)
  .Range("C1:C" & lLastRow).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrTime)
  .Range("B1:B" & lLastRow).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yy"
  .Range("C1:C" & lLastRow).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Axel, thanks for replying. I will go check it in a few minutes. If it is not too much to ask, request you to explain what the code is actually doing.

That will help in future in configuring it for different situations.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a ready to use solution - like it will never be with my answers. It is a approach. And it shows, that recording macros is only the first step to use macros. You need to deal with VBA as programming language. This can't be done in an posting here. Use tutorials and/or the help function in the VBA editor. My variable names should be self explained. In this case you can simply replace the `TextToColumn` part in your recorded macro with the content of my macro. Of course you must adapt the columns A, B and C to your G, H and I.

Comment: Thanks a lot Axel Richter ! It has worked perfectly. 

Just changed the columns and removed an extra column at the end the csv came out with correct formatting.